# How to match all lines sharing same words

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I'm using integrated search feature with in Visual Studio Code. In search criteria there is regEx way of searching things.

I'm trying to search complete CSV (using Visual Studio Code IDE), exact match of the first field of the row that contain word "Mamba" and lines that mach same MAC address (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx) if the line is containing "Mamba"?

I have CSV that I need to parse using regEx.

```
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-69,6,11:21:27
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-68,6,11:21:29
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:75:20,-69,6,11:21:27
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:75:20,-68,6,11:21:29
,1C:28:AF:8E:73:31,-73,52,11:21:12
,1C:28:AF:8E:75:32,-75,52,11:21:14
,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-77,52,11:21:17
,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-73,52,11:21:12
,1C:28:AF:8E:75:32,-75,52,11:21:14
,1C:28:AF:8E:75:20,-77,52,11:21:17
eduroam,8C:7A:15:55:58:18,-88,6,11:21:12
eduroam,8C:7A:15:55:58:18,-88,6,11:21:14
eduroam,8C:7A:15:55:58:18,-88,6,11:21:17
```

After applying regular expression, I should have this seleceted as result:

```
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-69,6,11:21:27
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-68,6,11:21:29
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:75:20,-69,6,11:21:27
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:75:20,-68,6,11:21:29
,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-77,52,11:21:17
,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-73,52,11:21:12
,1C:28:AF:8E:75:20,-77,52,11:21:17
```

NOTE:
The lines that contain the search string/pattern "Mamba" is not precede other lines with the same MAC address.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Will the lines that contain the search string/pattern "Mamba" always precede other lines with the same MAC address? What exactly do you mean with 'lines that *contain* "Mamba"'? An exact match of the first field of the row? Or a substring match in the first field or even anywhere in the line? Why do you have the requirement to use a regular expression? (Probably not possible.)

Comment: I try this `^Mamba+.*$` but that give me only the first part of the question. Selected all lines containing "Mamba"

Comment: @SashaMilic Please [edit] your question to add requested information. Be more specific. How exactly did you try the regular expression? What feature of vscode or what command did you use? Add some background information. What are you trying to achieve? Extract the matching lines from a file?

Comment: @Bobo I edit the question. I hope is more understandable.

Comment: I don't really understand your sentence "The lines that contain the search string/pattern "Mamba" *is not precede* other lines with the same MAC address.". I try to rephrase my question. In your example, the lines with "Mamba" precede the other lines with the same MAC address, i.e. the lines with "Mamba" are come first, other lines with matching MAC addresses after the corresponding "Mamba" line. Is this always the case? If the order can be different, change your example to also show all possible orders.

Comment: The csv example is in original. So, each line contain `Name,MACaddress,Number,Time`. I need to filter all lines that contain word "Mamba" as a first word of the line. That can be done by using `^Mamba+.*$`. Then I need to check if the `MACaddress` of selected lines mach with some other line that do not have first word (ie. ,MACAddress,number,time)

Comment: Regarding `I need to parse using regEx` - no, you don't, that would just make things harder. See [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my understanding is

- get all line with **Mamba**, remember mac
- get all line with those mac

I came with this awk

```
awk -F, '$1=="Mamba" {  m[$2]=NR ; } $2 in m { print ;}'
```

where

- `-F,` use `,` as separator
- `$1=="Mamba" {  m[$2]=NR ; }` remember in array `m` Mamba's mac
- `$2 in m { print ;}` if match, print

As suggested a shorter form

```
awk -F, '$1=="Mamba"{ m[$2] } $2 in m'
```

- no need to set `m[$2]`
- implicit `{print}` for condition `$2 in m`

---

please note, that if mac come before match with Mamba, it won't match

if data are

```
,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-77,52,11:21:17
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-69,6,11:21:27
```

first line won't be catch

Comment: Works like a charm.. Thanks.. I will search for: how to pipe results in to new file..

Comment: May I ask if there is another reason to keep the semicolons (other than readabiliy)? I also like more 'sparse' awk oneliners (Sometimes people don't leave any spaces at all and that's not readable).

Comment: @thanasisp 1) my first version was `awk -F, '$1=="Mamba" {  print ; m[$2]=NR ;next ; } $2 in m { print ;}'` 2) I do keep semicolon, even in multiline awk out of habbit, I might have had error when first using `awk`on SunOS 3, so don't steal my "precious" semicolons !!

Comment: ok, just asking, I have no plan to steal them :)

Comment: You don't need those semi-colons. You also don't need to set the array entry to `NR` as you don't use it, nor do you need `{ print ;}` as that's the default behavior given a true condition so the entire script could just be `awk -F, '$1=="Mamba"{  m[$2] } $2 in m'`

Answer (score 0):

Using `GNU sed`

```bsh
##> regex for Mac address
h2='[[:xdigit:]]{2}'
mac_addr="$h2(:$h2){5}"

sed -En "
  /^(Mamba|),$mac_addr,/G
  /^[^,]*,($mac_addr),.*\n\1\n/ba
  /^Mamba,.*\n/!d
  h
  s/^Mamba,($mac_addr),.*/\1/M
  x
  :a
  P
" file
```

---

Output:-

```
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-69,6,11:21:27
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-68,6,11:21:29
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:75:20,-69,6,11:21:27
Mamba,1C:28:AF:8E:75:20,-68,6,11:21:29
,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-77,52,11:21:17
,1C:28:AF:8E:73:24,-73,52,11:21:12
,1C:28:AF:8E:75:20,-77,52,11:21:17
```

---

- Append hold space which we use to store Mac addresses seen in only Mamba lines.
- When the current line 's Mac address, the second fields, matches somewhere in hold space, print the current line
- Only for Mamba line we extract the Mac address.